# regex :$1 don't get the right data,how to got it right?

Tags: regex, perl

```
while (<DATA>)
{print  "$1" if /((?:\d+)(?:\s*)){5}/;}
```

**DATA**

```
12 14 43 43 41  
35 43 543 63 63
```

output: `4163`

I wonder why the output isn't `$1`

Comment: Doesn't compile https://eval.in/118822 and what is literal expected output?

Comment: There is an extra bracket `(?:\s*))` perhaps should be `(?:\s*)`. What do you actually want to print here?

Comment: @Tom Fenech, Not so. There should be a capture. It's not an extra `)`, it's a missing `(`. Fixed.

Comment: The extra `(?:)` groups are redundant. `((?:\d+)(?:\s*)){5}` is exactly equivalent to `(\d+\s*){5}`.

Answer (score 2):

> *I wonder why the output isn't `$1`*

Double-quoted strings interpolate variables. If you want `$1`, you'd use `print '$1';`.

---

`$1` contains what the first capture of the most recently successful regex match captured.

Let's examine the following similar program, which is a simplification of the one currently in the OP.

```
while (<DATA>) {
   print $1 if /(\d+\s*){5}/;
}

__DATA__
12 14 43 43 41  
35 43 543 63 63
```

For the first pass of the while loop, the last time the one and only capture in the regex matched, it captured `41` followed by a newline. This is then printed by `print "$1"`.

For the second pass of the while loop, the last time the one and only capture in the regex matched, it captured `63` followed by a newline. This is then printed by `print "$1"`.

As such, the output is

```
41
63
```

---

If you wanted the output to be

```
12 14 43 43 41  
35 43 543 63 63
```

You could do

```
print $1 if /((?:\d+\s*){5})/;
```

Or you could do

```
print $_ if /(?:\d+\s*){5}/;
```

Comment: The `\s*` will also match the trailing newline, so `41` and `63` would appear on separate lines.

Comment: @Borodin, Then I incorrectly fixed the OP's code. I'll adjust my answer rather than trying to guess further.

Comment: I can't make any more sense of the original question than you did.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [Regexp::Debugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp%3a%3aDebugger).

But it would be easier to help you if you told us what result you wanted to get.